# xcode 6.3 does not show all options for base sdks

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I am new to OS X development. Using Xcode 6.3 on yosemite. Why the base sdks option in build settings only showing 10.10 and 10.9 
Is it not possible to add other sdks under this option ? if it is then how can I do it ?

I understand that to support old platforms I need to set target sdk to lowest supported platform.
What I am trying to do here is to compile my code against an older sdk to ensure that my project is not calling any functions not available in old sdk.

Thanks,
Ahmed

Comment: Basically each version of Xcode will only contain a couple of SDKs.  I think you will get what you want with the 10.10 SDK as the compiler will tell you if you are calling methods not available in older SDKs; your main issue is managing the change from the oldest to the newest SDK (i.e. replaced classes and methods).  That requires querying the current OSX version and using different code paths at runtime.

Comment: Hmmm a bit of surprise for me, so the compiler knows which functions are not available in old sdk, without having the old sdks on the system ? can you kindly shed some light on it like how does it know about it to complain a compiler error. The second question about your second part of comment, is it not true that newer sdks have incremental additions of APIs i.e. the old functions are still there in newer APIS and not replaced ??

Comment: It's a pretty complicated subject but you will find more usual answers on this site (and perhaps Apple's) about how to do this properly.  I may have mis-represented the truth with my comment, but you don't need an old SDK.